# Community users can't see fields inside any section on page layout

Tags: community, page-layout, fields

I am attempting to implement self service for service cloud using salesforce communities. We now have the case list and the record page all set up. I have given the community profile their own page layout and assigned it to them.

The issue is that any field in the page layout that is inside a section is not being displayed on the case detail (record detail page). If I pull the fields outside of the section (any section) then the logged in community user can see the field based on the FLS I have set. This invisible field in section is also happening for admins going into the community to that record page.

What setting/configuration am I missing? Is it intended that page layout sections are not displayed on record detail pages in a community?

[image: case page layout only two fields outside of section are shown]

[image: Case record detail page in community. Only fields outside of sections are shown]

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of the section please?

Comment: I added screenshots @manjit5190 but this is happening for any section on the page layout. We are using the Case Record Detail page in Community to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this issue was because our designer had CSS to hide all sections that I was not aware of.

Comment: Thanks for closing this.